# Can I build a custom button to submit a opportunity into approval process?

Tags: javascript, custom-button, approval-process, custom, button

Is there any way to create a custom JS button that will push a opportunity into one of my specific approval processes?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not standard "Submit for Approval" button? Are you performing any additional operations before submitting?

Answer (score 3):

use this code. It will help you.

Javascript:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/24.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/24.0/apex.js")} 
sforce.apex.execute("SAPRequest","SendApprovalRequest", {id:"{!Account.Id}"}); 
window.alert("Record sent for approval" );
```

Apex:

```
WebService static void SendApprovalRequest(string id) {

// create the new approval request to submit
Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
req.setComments('Submitted for approval. Please approve.');
 req.setObjectId(id);
// submit the approval request for processing
Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.Process(req);
// display if the reqeust was successful
System.debug('Submitted for approval successfully: '+result.isSuccess());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Tushar did you can try that..

Else one more option..

Use standard URL expression `$Action`

```
{!URLFOR( $Action.Opportunity.Submit,  Opportunity.Id  )}
```

### Using custom URL button

**First create a custom URL button**

[image]

---

### Another option using custom Javascript button

**create a custom javascript button**

**If you want check some condition in javascript and then perform submit then try like that**

```
window.open("{!URLFOR( $Action.Opportunity.Submit,  Opportunity.Id  )}");
```

[image]